# Changing [xenko] tag to [stride]

Tags: discussion, tags

The *Xenko* game engine [has been renamed to *Stride*](https://stride3d.net/blog/xenko-has-been-renamed-to-stride/), and I just [asked a question about it](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/182379/how-to-create-a-mesh-in-code), implicitly adding the new stride tag without checking for [xenko] first. Oops!

Since there is [only 1 question tagged [xenko]](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/xenko/), should it be renamed / changed to [[stride]](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/stride), or should it be made a synonym? The [xenko] tag does have some description, but I mostly added the same text to [stride] already (which is not yet peer-reviewed).

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a rename of the engine, I think it should be made a synonym of the new `stride` tag. This would help future visitors to see something "coherent" with the rest of the internet (those who have not been made aware that it was renamed, for example).

Answer (score 1):

As a side answer (which is orthogonal with [my other answer](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2841)), it's not atypical to include the term "engine" into the tag.

So I would suggest we use the tag `stride-engine` instead of just `stride`.

Comment: I thought so too, but saw that the Unity engine only uses [unity] aswell, and went with that.

Comment: Yeah, we can't "rename" a tag, we have to modify all the questions, or create a synonym, and unity was created like that. The scope this tag here is much smaller and easier to "get it right".

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought it was done on purpose for Unity. Of course, feel free to use [stride-engine] then!